# Invert Y axis in Konva

Tags: konvajs

I have to do a lot of drawing stuff with angles and I'm afraid of messing it up with the y axis going toward bottom. And I want the Y axis going upward.
I know that in normal canvas you can invert Y axis with a simple transform:

```
var stage = document.getElementById("stage");
const layer=stage.getContext("2d");
layer.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 3000);
```

But I do not know if I can do that in Konva. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to apply a negative scale `-1` and move a container to make it visible.

```
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  y: window.innerHeight,
  scaleY: -1
});
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/vuhuzuroca/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How can I solve the problem with texts, then? They are drawn inverted in the Y axis, too.

Comment: You can invert text too: `text.scaleY(-1)`.